# Angular Scroll on Click

Tags: angularjs

I am having an issue getting Angular Scroll to work.I am trying to scroll from the landing div to another section on the page with a button click. My code formatted really strangely, so let me know if further clarification is needed.

HTML

```
<div class="cover">
  <div class="big-logo">
    <i class="fa fa-trello"></i>
    <span> My Kanban</span>
    <br>
    <button class="arrow" ng-click="bc.toLists()" du-smooth-scroll>
      <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down fa-sm animated flash infinite" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="story-board content">
  <button class="add-list" ng-click="bc.addingList = !bc.addingList">
    Add List
  </button>
  <div ng-if="bc.addingList">
    <form ng-submit="bc.addList(bc.newList)">
      <input style="margin-left: 5px" ng-model="bc.newList.name"/>
      <button type="submit">+</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="list" ng-repeat="list in bc.lists">
    <button style="font-size: 10px;background: none;border:none; color: black" ng-click="bc.removeList(list)">x</button>
    <list-component list-obj="list"></list-component>  
  </div>
</div>
```

init.js

```
angular.module('kanban', ['duScroll'])
```

app.js

```
angular.module('kanban')
  .component('boardComponent', {
    templateUrl: 'app/components/board/board.html',
    controller: BoardController,
    controllerAs: 'bc'
  })

BoardController.$inject = ['EsService']

function BoardController(EsService) {
  var bc = this;
  bc.lists = EsService.getLists();
  bc.addingList = false;

  bc.removeList = function(list){
    EsService.removeList(list.id);
  }

  bc.addList = function(list){
    EsService.createList(list);
    bc.newList = {};
  }

  bc.toLists = function() {
    bc.cover = angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName('cover'));
    bc.content = angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName('content'));
    bc.cover.scrollTo(bc.content, 0, 1000);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a JQuery free answer, you can use [$anchorScroll](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll)

Create your anchor link:

```
<button ng-click="$ctrl.scrollTo('anid')">Scroll</button>
```

Create the anchor to scroll to:

```
<div id="anid">Land here</div>
```

Then your controller:

```
controller: function($anchorScroll) {
  this.scrollTo = function(id) {
    $anchorScroll(id);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Is there any way to create a slower scrolling animation using this method?

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend letting your controller handle the scrolling as opposed to the directives. You will have much tighter control that way and can therefore debug any issues.

Here's an example using the `scrollToElement` method. Once you have this logic in place you can switch it out to any method you need.

[Here's a working demo](http://codepen.io/graemegeorge/pen/xOmRPG)

```
angular
  .module('app', ['duScroll'])
  .component('cmpExample', {
    templateUrl: 'path/to/template.html',
    controller: function($document) {
      var vm = this;

      vm.scrollTo = function(id) {
        $document
          .scrollToElement(
            angular.element(document.getElementById(id)), 0, 1000
          );
      }
    }
  });
```

html

```
<button ng-click="$ctrl.scrollTo('target')">

<div id="target">Content further down the page</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It is still not triggering the scroll unfortunately. I will keep trying.

Comment: Perhaps the plugin isnt being loaded?

Comment: I thought about that, but I definitely have the CDN script in my index.html and the duScroll dependency loaded too.

Comment: Never mind! I found the problem. I needed to inject $document into my controller

Comment: Ah probably my fault. I had it in my demo but not the code example. Ive updated. Apologies. Glad you could resolve.